# How to add spinner while timeout in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to create a simple code verification that checks to code value on key up event and while it's checks - it should show a spinner - but when the timeout has ended then it should displays a markup accordingly (invalid or check mark).

Here is the controller

```
        angular.module("app", []);

angular.module("app").controller("MainController", function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.searchStr = "";

  $scope.arrResults = [];

  $scope.valCode = "666666";
  $scope.isShowSpinner = false;
  $scope.errorMsg = "";
  $scope.isSuccess = false;
      $scope.checkCode = function () {
      let isError = false;
      $timeout.cancel(debounce);
      if ($scope.codeArr.join("") == $scope.valCode) {
        console.log($scope.codeArr.join(""));
      }

      if ($scope.codeArr.join("").length == 6) {
        $scope.isShowSpinner = true;
        var debounce = $timeout(function () {
          // debugger;
          $scope.errorMsg = "";
          $scope.isSuccess = false;

          if ($scope.codeArr.join("") != $scope.valCode) {
            isError = true;
            $scope.errorMsg = "Invalid Code";
          }
        }, 2000);
        $timeout(function () {
          $scope.isShowSpinner = false;
          if ($scope.errorMsg.length) {
            $scope.isSuccess = false;
          } else {
            $scope.isSuccess = true;
          }
        }, 50);
      }
    };


  angular.element(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).ready(function () {
      var body = $("body");

      $("body input").on("input", function (e) {
        let t = $(e.target);
        let sib = t.next("input");

        if (isNaN(parseInt(this.value))) {
          e.preventDefault();
          this.value = null;
          return false;
        } else {
          if (!sib || !sib.length) {
            sib = body.find("input").eq(0);
          }

          sib.select().focus();
          return true;
        }
      });

      function getSmsValue(e) {
        let isError = false;

        e.preventDefault();
        var debounce = null;
        smsCharsArr = [];
        $(".sms-input").each(function () {
          let smsValue = this.value;
          if (!!smsValue && smsValue !== "") {
            smsCharsArr.push(smsValue);
            $scope.codeArr = smsCharsArr;
          }
        });
      }

      body.on("blur", "input", getSmsValue);
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the markup of the indications :

```
<div ng-if="isShowSpinner" class="spinner-border" role="status">
      <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="isSuccess">
      <span><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div ng-if="errorMsg.length" class="row">
    <h1>{{errorMsg}}</h1>
  </div>
```

So when there are 6 digis - there is a debounce of 2 second to check if the code is correct - while it's checks i want to show the spinner - but when the timeout had ended - i want to hide the spinner and show the results - "invalid" text or "check" icon....

The correct code is 666666 ,
Here is [an example](https://codepen.io/royBarak80/pen/bGEvdNm)
Thanks

Comment: I use the very simple ngx-spinner component. It looks cool, and it's very simple to use. Here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner

Comment: Thanks buddy - i'm using AngularJS 1.7...